# Get 'None' from website by using beautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am new joiner and doing self study for crawling. I tried to get the information from Disneyland
https://www.hongkongdisneyland.com/book/general-tickets/1day-tickets-j

I tried to crawl the price from the website, but it return "None", the result should be HK$639

```
url5 = 'https://www.hongkongdisneyland.com/book/general-tickets/1day-tickets-j'
r = requests.get(url5)
sp = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
door = sp.find('div', class_='container')
price = door.find('p', class_='price')
print(price)
```

My concept of beautifulSoup: It parse the website to be html and I can use find/find_all to find the information by using 'div', 'p', and by its class. Please correct me if it is wrong, thank you.

Comment: It is possible that they dynamically load the content of the page. BeautifulSoup is just an html parser. If you want to handle dynamic content take a look at [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Thank you. I have another question. How could I know the website is dynamic content?

Answer (score 1):

The page is loaded by JavaScript.So to pull out the desired data, you can use selenium with bs4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service,options=options)
url = 'https://www.hongkongdisneyland.com/book/general-tickets/1day-tickets-j'
driver.get(url)
#driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml') 

price = soup.select_one('p:-soup-contains("General Admission:") > strong').text
print(price)
```

**Output:**

```
HK$639
```

Comment: Thank you. But it show a error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/meiwa/Learning/Project/Trip Planner/sel_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    price = soup.select_one('p:-soup-contains("General Admission:") > strong').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'